# What is Ext.namespace, how should we use them?

Tags: javascript, extjs, namespaces, extjs4.2

I came across to `Ext.namespace()` in the project that I am working on. 
I looked in **[Sencha's website](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-namespace)** and the explanation was not very helpful.

This is what they are saying:

> Creates namespaces to be used for scoping variables and classes so
>   that they are not global. Specifying the last node of a namespace
>   implicitly creates all other nodes.

```
Ext.namespace('Company', 'Company.data');
```

They also mention that `Ext.ns('Company.data')` is preferable.

*I apologize if this question seems simple or dumb, but I really want to completely understand this concept. Thanks in advance*

**This is what is not very clear to me:**

- If I have `Ext.namespace('Company', 'Company.data')` at the top of my JS page, does this mean that it carries all the other function name and variables (like a global scope)?
- What exactly 'Company' and 'Company.data' stand for in `Ext.namespace('Company', 'Company.data')`?
- Why new convention `Ext.ns('Company.data')` does not have 'Company' like in `Ext.namespace`?
- What does this mean `Specifying the last node of a namespace implicitly creates all other nodes`?
- When exactly this idea should be used?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First off, this is what `Ext.ns('Company.data')` is roughly equivalent too:

```
if (!Company) var Company = {};
if (!Company.Data) Company.Data = {};
```

Basically, it is just a shortcut for defining deeply nested structures
of objects. It is useful if your project structures this way; I've seen
projects with a Java backend that duplicate the
`com.company.app.data.package` package names in JavaScript, for which
`Ext.ns` is a nice shortcut.

---

Addressing your questions point by point:

> - If I have `Ext.namespace('Company', 'Company.data')` at the top of my JS page, does this mean that it carries all the other function name and variables (like a global scope)?

No. You have to add to `Company.Data`, like `Company.Data.newVal = 5;`.

> - What exactly 'Company' and 'Company.data' stand for in `Ext.namespace('Company', 'Company.data')`?

They are names, chosen by you, following your projects convention.

> - Why new convention `Ext.ns('Company.data')` does not have 'Company' like in `Ext.namespace`?

Because 'Company' is implied. That is, `Ext.ns('Company',
'Company.data')` is like:

```
if (!Company) var Company = {};
if (!Company) var Company = {};
if (!Company.Data) Company.Data = {};
```

This makes it easier to see why the first 'Company' is redundant.

> - What does this mean `Specifying the last node of a namespace
>     implicitly creates all other nodes`?
> - When exactly this idea should be used?

I answered these two above.

Comment: it's more like:

      if (window["Company"] === undefined) window["Company"] = {};

Answer (score 3):

Ext.namespace is really only useful if you want to define your own classes without using Ext.define.

The example below requires the namespaces to be created ahead of time:

```
Company.data.Form = Ext.extend(...); //this is the old way of defining classes
```

The standard way for creating ExtJS classes is:

```
Ext.define('Comany.data.Form', {...});
```

This method creates the namespaces for you automatically.